# Chart not rendering with variable in formatter callback function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I have a Highcharts graph in my Rails application, which has a javascript callback function in the `xaxis` `formatter` to get data:

```
spider_chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
  f.chart(polar: true, type: 'line', height: @height)
  f.xAxis(
    categories: categories.map{ |c| [@survey.id,c.id, c.name] },
      formatter: %|function() {return '<a href="http://localhost:3000/dashboards/spiders?level=2&survey_id=' + this.value[0] + '&category_id=' + this.value[1] + '">' + this.value[2] + '</a>';}|.js_code }
  )
  f.series(name: "Gemiddelde van huidige score", data: current_scores, pointPlacement: 'on')
  f.legend(enabled: @legend, align: 'center', verticalAlign: 'top', y: 10, layout: 'vertical')
end
```

When I use a hard coded url it works:

```
formatter: %|function() {return '<a href="http://localhost:3000/dashboards/spiders?level=2&survey_id=' + this.value[0] + '&category_id=' + this.value[1] + '">' + this.value[2] + '</a>';}|.js_code }
```

When I use a variable inside it doesn't work. It doesn't give an error, the graph is just not rendered:

```
formatter: %|function() {return '<a href="' + @environment + '/dashboards/spiders?level=2&survey_id=' + this.value[0] + '&category_id=' + this.value[1] + '">' + this.value[2] + '</a>';}|.js_code }
```

The variable `@environment` is correctly filled with `http://localhost:3000`.
When I use `window.location.hostname` then it also works:

```
formatter: %|function() {return '<a href="https://' + window.location.hostname + '/dashboards/spiders?level=2&survey_id=' + this.value[0] + '&category_id=' + this.value[1] + '">' + this.value[2] + '</a>';}|.js_code }
```

Unfortunately this is not always filled correctly, so I need have a function in my controller to determine the correct environment.

So how can I make sure that the `@environment` variable can be used?

Comment: Did you try to affect `@environment` to a variable and use this variable in the return expression ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, `@environment` is already a variable?

Comment: I know but some times with highcharts I had to initiate a local variable to use it in tooltip so maybe its the same for the xAxis.

Comment: I don't know much about ruby on rails (and lazy highcharts) but in  Highcharts `formatter` is a callback function. The `@environment` variable might be not available in the scope where the function is called.